# How to get parent node from child in json using d3js as Force Layout?

Tags: d3.js, parent-child, geometry, force-layout

I have used d3js for display the map and set the location by using Force Layout as a circle.

I have a map of a country and in that when I click on any particular state I remove my svg and build again by getting d (child records) from json.

Now the problem is that I need to come back and set the parent node when I click on back button that is Country map comes and need to set the state link and node again.

Do I need to use for loop to check all the records in json?

There is  one solution I found to store last parent node in the array and use that to come back but I don't know How to set parent node because on click event it always getting child records on click function.

So How to get parent records on click event?

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good idea to store your data into array but not good for those which are having big data.

As you mentioned that on click event you get the new record of the selected state so it is better to store the record in the array as a second key record i mean

```
array[0] = "Parent record"
array[1] = "Child Record"
array[2] = "Sub Child Record"
```

So by this you can get record on the spot no need to loop over json now when you come back as you mentioned suppose from state to country than just reload the page by

```
document.location.reload()
```

so your array will be initialized with the null values so you can store new values by going to different state no need to get record from country and set because country would be your main page.

Comment: Thanks it works just need to reload the page right no need to get the parent records because on page first country map comes.